# Problems with package manager after uninstalling bumblebee

Tags: update-manager, bumblebee

I uninstalled Bumblebee, but now my video card is not working properly. I tried to update its video driver, but now I just got the message

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.

Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:

'E:Type 'ain' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bumblebee-stable-precise.list'
```

either when I try to update by terminal and also when I open the package manager.

I would be glad in having some help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: What do you mean by "my video card is not working properly"?

Comment: This is not a bug, please do not report it. That message is just caused by a malformed entry that starts with `ain` instead of `deb` or `deb-src`.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a major error, just a wrong line added in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bumblebee-stable-precise.list, and is in no way related to "video card is not working properly".

You can remove the Bumblebee PPA file to fix this using the commands below:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bumblebee-stable-precise.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you shouldn't see this error any more.

And if you want to continue having the Bumblebee PPA, re-add it using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
```